# Nifi failing to start due to missing snappyjava on int, but not on dev

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I have ansible scripts that install a docker container running nifi.  I've run these scripts on our dev box without issue.  However, when I run them on our int box I see the following error in the nifi-bootstrap.log, causing the whole nifi to die immediately at startup:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/nifi/work/snappy-1.0.5-libsnappyjava.so (No such file or directory)
```

I checked the dev server where this is running and there is no /data/nifi/work directory and libsnappyjava doesn't exist anywhere on that server according to mlocate.

The flow file is exactly the same between the two versions, I've done an md5sum to ensure that.  The only difference in the nifi.properties file is that the they each have their own VM's hostname injected into appropriate fields by ansible.  The nifi installation is part of a parent docker image that hasn't been touched and so should also be identical across images.

I'm using a nifi tarball created by my company, containing some company specific jars etc, but it should be built on top of the latest nifi version.

The only difference between the functional dev and non-functional int that I can tell is that I original installed a docker image running an older nifi version before upgrading the nifi to get the more recent nifi api.  I don't know if somehow running the old nifi before upgrading it would have made a change to our /data directory in some way preventing the upgraded nifi from failing?

So why is my int looking for snappyJava when dev seems fine without it?

Comment: i've seen this error on alpine based docker containers.

Comment: it's not directly connected to nifi, but it's connected to linux/java versions you are using